# pentaho spoon : how to insert value to column conditionnally?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

So in my table, I have a column `quantity` and `comment`.
If the value in `quantity` is more than 0, then I need to insert a string "available" to column `comment` , if it equals to 0 then "to order" and finally if it's less than zero, then "warning". What could be the best way?

edited:
Guess my question above doesn't show the whole work necessary.

At first, I have a text file where I get fields including `quantity`.

Then I do some modifications of data (on formula step, I do some calculations on `quantity`).

In the end I use `Table output` step to insert them into BD. One of the fields to insert is `quantity`.

My main question is :

Is it better to insert values to column `comment` after `Table output` step (when `quantity` is already added in BD) using SQL script step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** answer no longer applies with new question details **

If you are updating a database table, by far the best and most efficient solution is to do it in a single SQL statement.

In a Pentaho Job, add a SQL step (under scripting).

In that step enter the SQL command. It will be similar to:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET comment = 
    CASE 
        WHEN quantity > 0 THEN 'available'
        WHEN quantity < 0 THEN 'warning'
        ELSE 'to order'
    END
// next line optional, use it if you only need to update some of the records.
WHERE (insert conditions here if you need any)
```

As an extra comment, it's less than ideal to have two columns that should always be in sync, but depend on an external job to keep them in sync. There are techniques like database triggers or calculating the case/when while retrieving the rows in a select statement that eliminate the chance of having out of sync fields.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply :) I actually added some details on my post.

Comment: I indeed tried as you said, however it takes much longer time, I added this step after my 'table input' step (i explained newly on my post about other steps I made)

Comment: @ayay This answer is invalid with the new details you added. Since you only mentioned "I have a table", I assumed you were trying to enrich/update that one table. When the data comes from a different source, definitely add the comments fields in the stream and include them in the Table Output.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear at all. Which step can be used to add the comments fields ? I already have formula step where I do calculation on quantity fields. Don't think I can do something on the same step

Comment: @ayay nsousa's answer lists good options, though you could just add a second Formula step if you are more familiar with Excel-like formulas.

Comment: I made a second formula step and I get the result expected. Thanks a lot and sorry again that I didn't make things clear at first!

Answer (score 1):

You have basically 3 options:

1. A filter rows step to split the stream based on the value of quantity, then each of the output streams has an Add constants step to add the new field you want, then combine them again by connecting both Add constants steps to a dummy;
2. A user defined java expression
3. A javascript step.

Option 2 is probably the cleanest; option 3 is basically the same as option 2, but with javascript instead of java code; option 1 has the advantage of not requiring any code (though, as the alternative is a one liner, not really an issue). Plus, in option 1 order of rows isn’t necessarily maintained.

Comment: Formula step with a simple Excel formula, or also a Value Mapper. I Guess Value Mapper step would be better suited for additions.

Comment: I tend to not use the formula step, but you’re right, it’s an option too. Value mapper won’t work as he doesn’t know the input values necessarily.